# Nested routes loads the parent model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I  have a nested route structure like this:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('user', {path: '/user/:user_id'}, function() {
    this.route('followers', {path: '/followers'});
  });
});
```

when I hit the `user/123/followers` route I would expect that it automatically fetch the model from `user/123/followers`, but it just fetches the user model from `user/123` again. What do I need to add so it fetches the right data for the route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each route have your own model, and this isn't propaged, by default.

So `App.UserRoute` model, returns the current model like expected:

```
App.User.find(params.user_id)
```

But because `App.UserFollowersRoute` have your own model hook, then you have to provided it.
You can do this easily using the `modelFor`.

```
App.UserFollowersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.modelFor('user');
  }
});
```

The modelFor look for a model from a named route. So `modelFor('user')`, will retrieve the model from `App.UserRoute`.

And in your `user/followers` template, you will have the current user, in the current context:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="user/followers">          
  <h2>{{name}} followers:</h2>
  <ul>
  {{#each followers}}
      <li>{{name}}</li>
  {{/each}}
   </ul>
</script>
```

[Here a sample with this working](http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/cbuLq/)

Answer (score 0):

Ember will automatically call User.find(123) when you hit `/user/123/...` because that is the default model hook for `App.UserRoute`. If you want to fetch additional data when the followers route is accessed, define a model hook for `App.UserFollowersRoute`:

```
App.UserFollowersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    user = this.controllerFor('user');
    // Now find and return the list of followers
  }
});
```